# attempted relative import with no known parent package errors when trying to import from local folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this folder structure in my Python project:

```
MY-PROJECT
.vscode
myfolder1
├── .venv
├── myconfig.yaml
├── myproject.toml
├── poetry.lock
└── myfolder2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── config.py
    └── mycode.py
```

From `mycode.py` I am trying to do a `from . import __version__` and `from .config import configuration`. My understanding is that it should work as `mycode.py` is in the same folder as `__init__.py` and `config.py`, but I get the following error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
  File "Volumes/myvolume/myfiles/MY-PROJECT/myfolder1/myfolder2/mycode.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import __version__
```

Python version is `3.9.7` (using `poetry`).

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: You are probably running your program as a script `python myfolder2`, try running it as a module like `python -m myfolder2`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JukkaVaisanen! But as I am running the code in debugger mode from VSCode (sorry I should have mentioned that), so I don't select the execution mode (script vs module). What I am donig is selecting "Debug Python File", so perhaps I'll have to find a way to run as a module from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer :)

Instead of `.`, if you manually add the folder name the code works as expected.

```
from myfolder2 import __version__
```